# Reduce ntpdate timeout when DNS settings invalid?

Tags: networking, server, dns, ntp

I have an issue where ntpdate times out after exactly 80 seconds in the event that DNS is invalid (or in this case, host is stuck behind a firewall). I would like to bring this timeout down to something more reasonable, like 1 or 2 seconds.

```
# ntpdate -bud ntp.ubuntu.com  
23 Sep 08:39:56 ntpdate[9554]: ntpdate 4.2.4p8@1.1612-o Tue Apr 19 07:08:19 UTC 2011 (1) 
Looking for host ntp.ubuntu.com and service ntp 
Error : Name or service not known 23 Sep 08:41:16 ntpdate[9554]: can't find host ntp.ubuntu.com

23 Sep 08:41:16 ntpdate[9554]: no servers can be used, exiting
```

Note that the `-t` option does not seem to help here, because it only seems to kick in when the server is reachable, plus the default value is 1 second.

lsb_release: `10.04.4 LTS`

uname: `2.6.32-43-server #97-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 5 16:56:41 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

In case that DNS is correctly configured, using an invalid NTP server will immediately timeout:

```
# ntpdate -bud ntp.ubuntu.comm
23 Sep 09:47:39 ntpdate[6523]: ntpdate 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Mon Apr 13 13:39:47 UTC 2015 (1)
Looking for host ntp.ubuntu.comm and service ntp
Error resolving ntp.ubuntu.comm: Name or service not known (-2)
23 Sep 09:47:39 ntpdate[6523]: Can't find host ntp.ubuntu.comm: Name or service not known (-2)
23 Sep 09:47:39 ntpdate[6523]: no servers can be used, exiting
```

So I really think this is more of a DNS resolve issue than ntpdate, but please help me find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know how to fix `ntpdate`, but you could first test the dns lookup with a command like

```
nslookup -timeout=1 ntp.ubuntu.com.
```

It exits 1 on timeout or fail to resolve.

Comment: This'll work for now as I need the fix quickly. I'll just chain the commands together. Thanks!